# How should I reference the data from my api in my component?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api

App.js

```
import { Text, View, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';

const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/users/';

const User = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>Name: {props.fname} {props.lname}</Text>
    <Text>Country: {props.country}</Text>
  </View>
);
const renderUser = ({item}) => <User fname={item.results[0].name.first} lname={item.results[0].name.last} country={item.results[0].location.country}/>;

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
  fetch(API)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {setUsers(json);});}, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{}</Text>

      <Button title="add a user" onPress={() => {
        fetch(API)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {setUsers(json);}), []}}
      />

      <FlatList data={users} renderItem={renderUser}/>

    </View>
  );
}
```

when I create a User, how should I reference the first and last name as well as the country from json? After looking online I thought this (item.results[0].name.first) was the way I was supposed to reference it but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong

Comment: can you preview how the JSON format returned from your API?

Comment: yep, i got the api wrong, search up https://randomuser.me/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have set the wrong API. I just test:

https://randomuser.me/api/ returns correct results.

https://randomuser.me/api/users/ return `404 not found`.

**UPDATE:**

The response of API is:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "Mr",
        "first": "Harley",
        "last": "Green"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": {
          "number": 5662,
          "name": "Hoon Hay Road"
        },
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So you need to edit your code:

```js
...
const renderUser = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <User
        fname={item.name.first}
        lname={item.name.last}
        country={item.location.country}
      />
    </>
  );
};


export default function App() {
   return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Button
          title="add a user"
          onPress={() => {
            fetch(API)
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((json) => {
                setUsers(json);
              }),
              [];
          }}
        />

      
        <FlatList data={users.results} renderItem={renderUser} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: oops didn't realize I did that. I fixed that but i'm still not getting anything. Am i referencing the data properly when i made renderUser?

Comment: @LiamHorton check my edited answer